# Some basic questions about Jacobians of curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, of positive genus. Let $J$ denote its Jacobian. I would like to ask a couple of basic (I presume) questions:

0) Why is $J$ an algebraic variety?

1) For a number field $K$, is a $K$-rational point on $C$ mapped by the Abel-Jacobi map to a $K$-rational point on $J$?

2) When $C$ is an elliptic curve defined by the equation $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, is its Jacobian isomorphic to $C$ as algebraic varieties/is it birationally equivalent to $C$?

Thank you.

Comment: 0: This is a big question and an answer depends on what you've seen. Look up a proof in a textbook and try to find more specifically which parts you don't understand.

2: Yes, they are isomorphic. This is standard and is essentially proved in the standard proof that there is a group law on an elliptic curve.

Comment: I recommend J.S. Milne's course notes at http://www.jmilne.org/math/ His notes on elliptic curves gives a very accessible proof of answer 2.  His notes on abelian varieties gives a much more sophisticated proof of answer 0.